# SSH find modified file from certain day

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, terminal

I am trying to discover a modified file from a certain day. I have been using `find . -mtime -2` but I need to go back even further, this past Thursday and just Thursday.

I am not anywhere near proficient in unix commands so any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: close if you wish, but last time I checked offering advise for those of us not knowing but trying to learn a programming language, UNIX...hmmm, is very helpful. The answer below totally helped in discovery of new commands that I otherwise might not have ever found. Thanks for the direction @shiplu.mokadd.im, ps the answer has more reputation than all 6 of you closers combined...he thought it was on topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find files that were modified **after** last Thursday use this command

```
find . -newermt 'last Thursday'
```

Before last Thursday

```
find . -type f \
    -not \
    -newermt "2012-12-13 00:00:00"
```

Only Thursday

```
find . -type f \
    -newermt "2012-12-13 00:00:00" 
    -not \
    -newermt "2012-12-14 00:00:00"
```

The last Thursday was `2012-12-13`. When you search any file that has modification date  lower than Thursday in `find` it should be `-not newermt '2012-12-13'`. When you search Only files modified on this Thursday its lower than Wednesday but greater than Thursday. And yes you can omit `00:00:00` part if you wish.

**Note:** POSIX `find` does not have `-newerXY`. It has only `-newer`. To convert `-newermt "2012-12-13 00:00:00"` use this.

```
touch -d "2012-12-13 00:00:00" pointA

find . -type f \
        -not \
        -newer pointA
```

Comment: thanks so much, this returns modified files?

Comment: Yes. Modified files as list

Comment: That's useful notation, but not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).  Presumably, this is a version of GNU [`find`](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Time)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for raising the issue. I have added a POSIX compliant command. In fact I shouldn't have ignored [tag:unix] tag.